# How to Select Multiple dropdowns using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently am working on `selenium webdriver`. I am trying select the multiple dropdowns and it is the filter selection. once i selected multiple dropdown i will click on **Apply Filter** button then i will produce the result based on the selected filter section. so i am getting problem to select multiple drop down and can't able to click on **Apply filter** dropdown. Could you please help me to figure out how to use the code. am using java

Here is my sample code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ext-new-prs")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"))).selectByVisibleText("Center");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("periodId"))).selectByVisibleText("Last 52 Weeks");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("topographyId"))).selectByVisibleText("Center");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#topographyId > option[value=\"center\"]")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("centerId"))).selectByVisibleText("OAB");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("featureRequestId"))).selectByVisibleText("Include");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
```

Comment: We need to know what error you are getting, and probably the HTML

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: if am adding driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); the same error am getting

Comment: Implicit waits won't help with ElementNotVisibleExceptions.  Do `new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementIsVisible(element)))` (That code may not be exact, I'm writing off of my memory).

Answer (score 0):

*Something like below:-*

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement dBox1= (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("visualizationId"))).selectByVisibleText("Center");
actions.moveToElement(dBox1);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Comment: I used the above lines in my code but am getting error as follows Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: visualizationId

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void waitforElement (WebDriver driver , int Seconds , String Locator )
{
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, Seconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Locator)));
}
use this method
waitforElement(driver,30,"//div[@id='divGrid']");
call like this
By sundar
www.mjksundar.weebly.com
```